# PHP file not loading from apache's subdirectory

Tags: 16.04, apache2

I have installed apache+php on Ubuntu version 16.04.2 LTS

In `/var/www/html` folder I have `some.php` file and when I browse it from url: `localhost/some.php`, file loads.

Then I add folder "subd" in root directory, so now I have `/var/www/html/subd` and then into that directory I placed file `some.php`.

Now, if I browse address `localhost/subd/some.php` page not loading, there is error:

> This page isn’t working
>
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request

What I do wrong ?

Comment: Please run `ls -l localhost/subd/some.php` I suspect permission might be the issue

Comment: Probably, George meant `ls -l /var/www/html/subd`, then [edit] the question with the command's output.

Comment: @George ,  pa4080 - output from that command is: `-rw-r--r-- 1 user_name date some.php`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a permission error. We have to make sure all those `.php` files are executable. In your case `-rw-r--r--` means the owner of the file has read+write permission, while others in and outside of the group can only read the file. As a result, we have to change this by running:

```
chmod a+x /var/www/html/subd/*.php
```

This allows everyone to execute any php files in `subd`.
Also, please make sure to change the folder's permission as well:

```
chmod a+x /var/www/html/subd
```

More information about permission can be found [here](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abdb).
Hope this helps :)